# Convexity preferences

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, supply-and-demand, consumer-theory, preferences

What is the difference between convexity and strict convexity preferences? What is the difference between quasi-concavity and quasi-convexity? And is MRS still true in concave preferences?

Comment: 1. Have you tried searching for these concepts, e.g.; on Wikipedia? I get good results. 2. What do you mean by "is MRS still true"? MRS is a function, not a statement?